# AngularJS: Execute controller function from a nested directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a question regarding executing a function (defined inside a controller) from a directive, but with another directive between these two (so this directive just passes forward the function). I made a quick working example, but I think it's not the best solution to my problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/mS8Oea?p=preview

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div agg-events="" fn="ctrlFn(par1, par2)"></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

If someone knows how to do this in a better way, it would be very helpful to me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have already solved your problem but I fixed your plunker here: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3T6knP9ESTKV2z920AXp?p=preview)

The basis is to assign the function to your attribute not the evaluated function eg.

Do `fn="ctrFn"` and call the function in your directive.

Comment: Your're right, I already solved the problem. However one thing I didn't know is that you don't have to specifiy the parameters to pass to controller function, you only define the name of the function. I defined it like: fn2='eventsFn(par1, par2)'.  Thank you for the answer!

Comment: The effect of specifying the parameters will make a call to the function instead of just taking a reference to it.
yw.